# Major cache but only on WordPress site

Tags: cache, html

I have disabled all caching plugins, and I have cleared my browser cache, removed my temp browser files - How come I'm still not seeing my changes going trough on my WordPress page?

I wait 20min they eventually show up but not really a good workflow

Any pointers? Could I set up an `.htaccess` file or is it only on the server the magic happens?

I checked my dev tools network tab for info about cached elements and everything is new - it's a 200 Return value on requests in the browser.

I even did a flush of the DNS

**EDIT**

The changes I've made are markup changes like adding an extra `div` and give another an extra class maybe an additional widget box.

Comment: To clarify, what sort of changes are happening that you are noticing not being refreshed until ~20 mins later? For example, JavaScript code changes? Or content changes in the post?  Or updated PHP logic not appearing to change?

Comment: @JaredCobb I editted the question

Comment: Some web hosts will cache with other server side technology, such as Varnish or integrate with a 3rd party service like CloudFlare.  Have you contacted your host's support to validate if they run any caching for you on that level?

Comment: Disabling caching plugins may not be enough - they may have already written to your htaccess file, and not cleaned up after themselves. Worth checking.